# Window Duration within PipelineOptions in Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Been trying to dig how I could do this but I'm constantly getting the same error, which is the following...

```
An exception occured while executing the Java class. Value only available at runtime, but accessed from a non-runtime context:
```

Solved this issue before accessing `.get()` once the Pipeline was instantiated and configured, inside a custom DoFn that was needed.

My problem now is when defining the Duration of a Window within the Pipeline, which isn't a custom object such as the previously metioned one.

```java
@Description("Defaults to 5 (minutes).")
@Default.Long(5)
ValueProvider<Long> getWindowDuration();
```

I can't wrap my head around how to access that value once the Pipeline has been deployed, or if the current Window objects support PipelineOptions in some of its constructors...

```java
  .apply(
    options.getWindowDuration() + "min Window",
    Window.<GenericRecord>into(
              FixedWindows.of(
                Duration.standardMinutes(options.getWindowDuration().get()) 
                /** [Hardcoded so I can debug] Duration.standardMinutes(5) **/))
          .triggering(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane() 
          (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Window duration has to be specified when defining the pipeline (not during execution). So you should set it directly in the window object (for example, FixedWindows). The value you set does not necessarily have to come from a pipeline option.

Comment: I know that, but is there any possibility of setting it through PipelineOptions?

Comment: You can create your own PipelineOptions object and set get the value through that and set when defining your pipeline if that's what you meant. See here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params